# Restkit 0.2 nested object mapping

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, restkit-0.20

i have the following JSON i can't seem to map restkit 0.2

```
{
 "data":

    {"usersA":[
            {"name":"lal1","rank":"rank1"},
            {"name":"lal2","rank":"rank2"},
        ],

    {"usersB":[
            {"name":"lal1","rank":"rank1"},
            {"name":"lal2","rank":"rank2"},
            {"name":"lal3","rank":"rank3"},
        ],

    {"usersC":[
            {"name":"lal1","rank":"rank1"},
            {"name":"lal2","rank":"rank2"},
            {"name":"lal3","rank":"rank3"},
            {"name":"lal4","rank":"rank4"},
        ],  
    }
}
```

i created the following user class:

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * rank;

@end
```

mapped it like so:

```
RKObjectMapping *userArrayMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
[videoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name": @"name",@"rank": @"rank"}];
```

and called the data.users keyPath:

```
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userArrayMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                        pathPattern:HOME_SCREEN_API_URI
                                            keyPath:@"data.usersA"
                                        statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
```

this was fine,  and i got the "usersA" mapped to array of User classes with the following code:

```
__block NSMutableArray* dataArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:USERS_API
                                           parameters:nil
                                           success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                                  dataArr = mappingResult.array;
                                              }
                                              failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                  NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                                              }];
```

but i can't seem to map the "data" object into array of dictionaries holding the "usersA", "usersB" and "usersC".

i'm using restkit 0.2. and the only examples i could find are for previous versions...

any help would be greatly appreciated !

tx.

Comment: Is it just "usersA", "usersB" and "usersC", or will there be others in the future (like "usersXX") ? Do you know what they all are now? How many are there?

Comment: yes, it's just "usersA", "usersB" and "usersC". this is permanent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only have 3 different key paths in the response JSON, just create 3 response descriptors and add them all to the object manager. The only difference between each response descriptor is the key path:

1. @"data.usersA"
2. @"data.usersB"
3. @"data.usersC"

this solution isn't ideal if you have an unknown number or an arbitrary set of key paths, but it will work for you and is simple.

When you do this all of the mapped items will be returned in `mappingResult.array`, though if you need to you can find out the original key path for each object if you use `mappingResult.dictionary`.

Comment: first of all - thanks Wain, it's working. I'm really sorry but i  didn't explain my self right. what i wanted is to have a 'data' class which has 3 NSDictionaries class members: "usersA", "usersB", and "usersC". and that 'data' class would be populated from the mapping result with the "usersA" "usersB" and "usersC". so i would have a reflection of the resulting json into the 'data' class without doing any explicit assignment myself. is that possible?

Comment: So you could have a `Data` class, with 3 `NSMutableArray` properties that you map the `User` objects into. But the properties couldn't be dictionaries - but, your JSON in the question isn't actually valid, so perhaps your real JSON would give you keys to do it, though it seems unlikely.